# Collapsed performance

Tags: c#, wpf

Do elements with visibility set to `Collapsed` reduce performance when they aren't displayed?

I'm talking about large (200 items) `DataGrids` laying behind.

PD. I haven't built the `DataGrid` yet, and I don't have the actual data. Sorry if the question is not very worked, I couldn't figured out a proper manner of testing it by myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Items with their visibility set to collapsed are still part of the layout phase, so there's a (very minor) impact to performance if you have many collapsed items.  Their container still has to check to make sure they're not visible or hidden, so they'll get walked in the tree.

That being said, the impact is very small, and rarely the culprit to a real performance problem.

Comment: Thanks Reed, so having the items collapsed is almost the same as having them visible? If's so it's not the best idea to have some big DataGrids behind all the time...

Comment: @Sturm No - collpased is far cheaper than visible - but in general, I'd not have tons of large items around all of the time, if for no reason than the binding updates might be painful...

Answer (score 0):

They have a performance impact of around 20% if they were not collapsed (i.e. visible).

Comment: What version of .NET are you using for these timings?  My experience has often been closer to 2% vs. 20%...  Collapsed items tend to have very little impact in my measurements...

Comment: Where did you get your info?